# Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted with array

Tags: php, arrays, combinations, memory-limit

I am trying to make a function to generate all possible combinations. This part works well so the output would be

aaa
aab
aac
aad
...

But now i am trying to add an extension to each of the combinations so i want to add "HI" at the end like

aaaHI
aabHI
aacHI
aadHI

Iv tried the following but im getting this error. Is there a better way to do this that what i am doing?

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 100663409 bytes)

here is my script

```
function sampling($chars, $size, $combinations = array()) {

    # if it's the first iteration, the first set 
    # of combinations is the same as the set of characters
    if (empty($combinations)) {
        $combinations = $chars;
    }

    # we're done if we're at size 1
    if ($size == 1) {
        return $combinations;
    }

    # initialise array to put new values in
    $new_combinations = array();

    # loop through existing combinations and character set to create strings
    foreach ($combinations as $combination) {

        foreach ($chars as $char) {
            $new_combinations[] = $combination. $char;
            $new_combinations[] = implode($new_combinations, "HI");
        }
    }

    # call same function again for the next iteration
    return sampling($chars, $size - 1, $new_combinations);

}


// example
$chars = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z');

$output = sampling($chars, 3);

foreach($output as $do) 
{ 
    echo $do."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Either use the set_ini functions, or open up php.ini and increase the allowed memory size. Think about why you really need to do this before increasing the size.

Comment: iv tried that but its still not working

Comment: How big of an array are you trying to create?

Comment: if i dont use $new_combinations[] = implode($new_combinations, "HI"); it works fine. But if i add this line it dosent work

Comment: Probably becausae you're adding an additional 16/32 bytes to the end of each string. That adds up.

Comment: Your $new_comninations array grows progressively. Because you take all the combinations on the previous iteration and add them on the next. Of course you are running out of memory. Just don't do that.

Comment: By the way: `string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )`. Why do you use array as glue?

Comment: I think you're adding a copy of the array for each iteration by imploding the array? If that's even accepted. Maybe you're looking to just add 'HI' to your previous string then add . 'HI' on the line previously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really clear what you are going to do, but first of all, you are using `implode()` incorrectly. The first argument must be $glue and the second your array.

`string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )`

Secondly, your $new_combinations array is growing progressively on each step.

But if I understood what you were going to do, will this code work for you:

```
<?php

function sampling($chars, $size, $combinations = array()) {

    // if it's the first iteration, the first set
    // of combinations is the same as the set of characters
    if (empty($combinations)) {
        $combinations = $chars;
    }

    // we're done if we're at size 1
    if ($size == 1) {
        return $combinations;
    }

    // initialise array to put new values in
    $new_combinations = array();

    // loop through existing combinations and character set to create strings
    foreach ($combinations as $combination) {

        foreach ($chars as $char) {
            $tmp = $combination. $char;
            if ($size == 2) {
                $tmp .= '.com';
            }

            $new_combinations[] = $tmp;
            // I don't get what you were going to do with this line,
            // but this looks like a logical bug in your code
            //$new_combinations[] = implode(".com", $new_combinations);
        }
    }

    // call same function again for the next iteration
    return sampling($chars, $size - 1, $new_combinations);

}


// example
$chars = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z');

$output = sampling($chars, 3);

foreach($output as $do)
{
    echo $do."<br>".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: thanks i tried this but its showing like so "aa.coma.com" instead of "aa.com"